# How to get object support in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

### The value of the support object is null

> ### It is configured using retrofit and API, but ad support is not configured
>
> ```
> data class QuoteList(
>
>     @SerializedName("data")
>     val `data`: List<Datas>,
>     @SerializedName("page")
>     val page: Int,
>     @SerializedName("per_page")
>     val perPage: Int,
>     @SerializedName("support")
>     val support: Support,
>     @SerializedName("total")
>     val total: Int,
>     @SerializedName("total_pages")
>     val totalPages: Int
>
>
> )data class Support(
>     @SerializedName("text")
>     val text: String,
>     @SerializedName("url")
>     val url: String
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> enter image description here
> enter image description here
> ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fc2E.png)

Comment: Please provide the explanation of your problem/question.

Answer (score 0):

go to site that convert json to class: https://json2kt.com/

```
import android.R.id
```

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class QuoteList(

```
@SerializedName("page"        ) var page       : Int?            = null,
@SerializedName("per_page"    ) var perPage    : Int?            = null,
@SerializedName("total"       ) var total      : Int?            = null,
@SerializedName("total_pages" ) var totalPages : Int?            = null,
@SerializedName("data"        ) var data       : ArrayList<Datas> = arrayListOf(),
@SerializedName("support"     ) var support    : Support?        = Support()
```

)

data class Datas(

```
@SerializedName("id"            ) var id           : Int?    = null,
@SerializedName("name"          ) var name         : String? = null,
@SerializedName("year"          ) var year         : Int?    = null,
@SerializedName("color"         ) var color        : String? = null,
@SerializedName("pantone_value" ) var pantoneValue : String? = null
```

)

data class Support(

```
@SerializedName("url"  ) var url  : String? = null,
@SerializedName("text" ) var text : String? = null
```

)